# Make property thread safe

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a property (atomic, retain) NSString *identifier which may be read from multiple thread. So which is the correct way to make it thread safe-

```
- (NSString *)identifier
   {   @synchronized(self)   
      {
          return [_identifier retain] autorelease];   
      }

   }
```

or

```
  - (NSString *)identifier
       {    @synchronized(identifier)   
          { 
              return [_identifier retain] autorelease];   
          }

       }
```

Infact, i want to know the purpose of key parameter is @synchronize(key). Thanks for you help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "thread safe" in this context? Just that it won't crash when accessed, or that it has some special thread related functionality?

Comment: The auto-generated getter, with the (default) `atomic` attribute will do the right thing; why are you generating the getter yourself?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, by thread-safe i mean data integrity.@Droppy atomic doesn't guarantee thread safety.

Comment: Nor does your code. It does exactly the same thing as atomic, just slower. And why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: @gnasher729, how do you know atomic has same implementation? Apple made the implementation of atomic hidden, so there is no way to say that Apple use @synchronize() in their atomic implementation? And Apple clearly states that atomic doesn't provide thread safety, it only guarantee whole/viable value.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for @synchronized is the object on which synchronisation happens. Every other @synchronized(self) with the same object will stop while another @synchronized(self) is executing.

You might want to post code that actually compiles. That would tell you that the second one doesn't actually compile.